# How to remove .0 from number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one column DOB(Year) in df dataframe, which consist values like below:

```
DOB(Year)
1990.0
1998.0
2015.0
2017.0
```

I want to remove .0 from all values.

I have tried

```
df[DOB(Year)]=df[DOB(Year)].astype(str)
df[DOB(Year)]=df[DOB(Year)].str.replace(".0$", "",regex=True)
```

But resulting column values are nan.
Can anyone please suggest solution for this?

Comment: This code should not yield NaNs, you can always use `pd.to_numeric(df['DOB(Year)'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a safe method that works on numeric/string input:

```
df['DOB(Year)'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['DOB(Year)'], errors='coerce')
                     .round().convert_dtypes()
                  )
```

Example (as new column):

```
   DOB(Year)  DOB(Year)_converted
0     1990.0                 1990
1     1998.0                 1998
2     2015.0                 2015
3     2017.0                 2017
4  2011.0001                 2011
5        abc                 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[DOB(Year)]=df[DOB(Year)].astype('int')
```

Comment: Note that `astype(int)` won't work if the dtype is originally string

Comment: Tried both int and 'int' but getting valueError: Cannot convert no -finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: Whatever. You can use `"int64"` or just `int` or `np.int32`

Comment: @Shital Do you need to keep nan values? If yes - try to `fillna(0)` to avoid nan but you will know that zero it is nan in this column because probability of year=0 is low)
or you can drop row with nan values.